# Ubuntu 12.10 - Can't find my logs

Tags: ubuntu, logging, authentication, pam, saslauthd

Up until few days ago, my Ubuntu 10.04 worked like a clock.

Then I switched to Ubuntu 12.10 and things don't work the same way with this setup. First, the new system wasn't logging any mail activity, so I had to edit `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` and now the mail logs okay.

I am still not happy because the file `/var/log/auth.log` is empty and I can't find any information how to enable PAM activity logging.

I must add that even my `/var/log/syslog` is also empty!

I wonder what other logs are switched off be default. I am sure some folks with Ubuntu 12.10 went through the same ordeal.

Comment: You've edited your question. Does that mean, that your syslog isn't empty anymore (if it is still empty, what does `dmesg` show?) What is your specific question?

Comment: My question is: **How do I enable the PAM log (/var/log/auth.log)? What other logs in Ubuntu are disabled by default?** Obviously, I can't use a server that doesn't log failed logins.

Comment: Add that to your question. I can't help you, but a specific question will more likely be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this info related to Ubuntu 10.04:

[Default rsyslog configuration for Ubuntu 10.04](https://gist.github.com/909386)

After tweaking my conf, thing are slowly starting to work.